# Implementations of public members in an internal protocol extension are forbidden -- sometimes?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift-protocols

Let's consider this arguably not unreasonable code:

```
internal protocol MyP: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var p: Int { get }
}

internal extension MyP {
    public var debugDescription: String {
        return "MyP(\(self.p))"
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, too. Now let's add a struct that, by every-so-nasty design reasons, is `public`:

```
public struct MyS: MyP {
    internal var p = 3

    public func foo() {}
}
```

*Now* I get:

> Error: property 'debugDescription' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'CustomDebugStringConvertible'

Funny enough, if I declare this struct in another file, Debug builds are fine and only Release builds error out.

So is this a bug in some optimization, or a language "feature"¹, as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584069/swift-internally-implement-public-protocol#comment66478089_39584069) suggests? Shouldn't it *always* error out then, instead of letting me continue happily until I release-build?

---

1. Semantically, the warning/error seems naive. Since `MyP` is internal, external users of `MyS` won't see `debugDescription`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Persists in Swift 3.1.